# Maior palavra em uma frase na lista - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

O código em Python **precisa achar a maior palavra na frase digitada que será armazenada na lista, sendo exibida posteriormente**.

A única coisa que eu sei sobre a resolução desse código é usando a função **max()** e que **meu código executa, mas não retorna, exatamente, o que eu quero**.

Exemplo:

```
Entrada:
['Eu acho que vi um gatinho']
```

```
Saída:
['gatinho']
```

Meu código está assim:

```
text = input().split()

maxstring = list(map(str, text))

print (max(maxstring))
```

Com saída **vi** ao invés de **gatinho**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro, a linha abaixo é completamente desnecessária:

```
maxstring = list(map(str, text))
```

Quando você faz o `split` de uma *string* você já obterá uma lista de *strings*. Fazer um `map` para convertê-las em *string* novamente seria redundante.

Segundo, a função `max` utilizará o operador maior, `>`, para definir quem é o maior valor. Quando você utiliza esse operadores em *strings* o resultado respeitará a ordem alfabética. Ou seja, o retorno que você obteve é `vi` pois ela será a última palavra quando postas em ordem alfabética.

Você quer a maior palavra e isso demanda comparar os **tamanhos das *strings***. A função `max` possui um parâmetro chamado `key` em que você pode passar um objeto chamável e, quando definido, o retorno deste objeto para cada itemn da lista que será utilizado como base de comparação. Como é tamanho que estamos falando, basta utilizar a função `len`:

```
max(text, key=len)
```

Comment: É mesmo, tinha esquecido do `len`. No caso de eu usar a função `min()` ele me retorna o menor elemento de `text`?

Comment: @AlexFeliciano Se utilizar a mesma lógica, sim.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

```
max(text, key=len)
```

Onde `text` é a lista com a string fatiada

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar a seguinte lógica:

1. Capturar uma frase qualquer e adicioná-la em uma lista;
2. Percorrer esta lista e capturar o tamanho de cada palavra;
3. Inserir o tamanho de cada palavra em outra lista;
4. Percorrer as duas listas simultaneamente associando cada palavra de maior tamanho ou seu respectivo nome.

Com esta lógica implementei o seguinte código:

```
frase = input('Digite a frase: ').split()
tam_palavras = list()
for palavra in frase:
    tam_palavras.append(len(palavra))

maior = max(tam_palavras)
print('Maior(es) palavra(s):')
for a, b in zip(frase, tam_palavras):
    if b == maior:
        print(a)
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/btolifgs-solkarped) o funcionamento do programa.

Observe que quando executamos o código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite a frase:` . Neste momento devemos digitar uma frase qualquer e pressionar `enter`.

Depois de termos inserido a referida frase o código executará o **1º for**. É por intermédio dele que será montada a lista `tam_palavras`, na qual será armazenada o tamanho de todas as palavras que, porventura, estiverem em `frase`. Em seguida, é calculado o `tamanho` da maior palavra e armazenado na variável `maior`.

Posteriormente o código executa o **2º for** com a ajuda da função `zip`. É através dele que ambas as listas - frase e tam_palavras - serão simultaneamente percorridas. Além disso o bloco `if` que se encontra dentro do `2º for`, verificará se o tamanho `"b"` de cada palavra é igual a **maior**. Caso positivo, a palavra `"a"`, pertencente à lista `frase` será exibida na tela.

**Observação**

A utilização do **2º for** é altamente necessário. Pois, caso exista na frase mais de uma palavra de maior tamanho, todas elas serão exibidas.

**Exemplo 1**

Se a frase digitada for

```
Eu acho que vi um gatinho
```

A Saída será...

```
Maior(es) palavra(s):
gatinho
```

Neste caso temos uma frase com apenas **uma** palavra de maior tamanho, que é `gatinho`, e possui **7** letras.

**Exemplo 2**

Se a frase digitada for:

```
Eu acho que vi um gatinho e uma gatinha
```

A saída será...

```
Maior(es) palavra(s):
gatinho
gatinha
```

Neste caso temos uma frase com **duas** palavras de maior tamanho, que são; `gatinho` e `gatinha`. Neste caso cada uma das duas palavras possuem **7** letras.